# Web part mysteriously prevents saving edits to webpart-page

Tags: 2010, web-part, visual-web-part

I've got a mystery problem with a visual webpart in SP2010.

The webpart itself is working perfectly.
Weird thing is that after you add an instance of this particular webpart to a page (by editing a webpart page, adding the webpart to a zone, and saving the page) no saved changes to that page will  be persisted any more.

You can edit the page and press save without any errors. But no changes will be persisted - the page will always revert to it's original state after the save.
(NOTHING will be saved. Neither changes to the content nor changes to properties)

It's a true mystery.

What's even weirder is the way I managed to solve the problem.
I started removing code piece by piece until the problem vanished. Somehow the problem was caused by the mere existance of an  tag in the UC of the visual webpart!
I could not believe it - but after testing multiple times I could actually confirm it..
I had to completely remove all traces of repeaters in order to resolve the problem.
Even the mere presence of a repeater tag, completely empty, without any bindings or any content, would cause the problem to re-appear.

Unbelievelable, I know!

I didn't have time to stop and think about why this happened...I simply removed the repeater and went on with the project.

But now, a few months later, the problem has re-appeared again.
No changes will persist on a page where this web part is present.

What in the world could be causing this issue?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, the repeater tag is missing now and you are still getting the issue??

Comment: Do you have a custom tool part in your web part?

Comment: @spevilgenius : yes. The problem has returned despite the repeater tag missing.

Comment: @JamesLove : nope, the web part doesn't contain anything moderately advanced at all. just some some simple code to fetch list items and present html

Comment: Sounds weird! But, there has to be a reason! Anything of interest in the SharePoint logs to point to a problem? Just a thought...